# My django create user and profile signal doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-models, signals

```
#from signals.py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import User, Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()

#from models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from PIL import Image


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_paying_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created_at = timezone.now()
        self.updated_at = timezone.now()
        return super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    linked_in = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    objective = models.TextField(blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default="profile-pics/default.jpg/", upload_to="profile-pics")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.profile_pic.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (100, 100)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.profile_pic.path)


#from apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

When I create users from Django admin but the profiles never get created with my users. I have included code from various files in my Django project. I believe I have the correct code but maybe a fresh set of eyes will help. What am I doing wrong? Please let me know if you need to see additional code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will raise an exception because of the **`save()`** method missing some arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by adding:

```
default_app_config = 'users.apps.UsersConfig'
```

to my users/**init**.py.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'users.apps.UsersConfig', # instead of 'users'
    ...
]
```

had same problem, this solves for me